# Seach for a word in a .txt files and write few lines into a new .txt file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text

Please help me to create a script to perform a task as per described below.

I have 2 files, `A.txt` and `B.txt`. Content of `A.txt` like below

```
ITEM
name TICKY
title nice coffe drink
type DRINK
ITEM
name APPLE
title sweet tasty apple
type FRUIT
ITEM
name JUICE
title nice tasty drink
type DRINK
ITEM
name ORANG
title niice nice orange
type FRUIT
ITEM
name CHERY
title nutritious rich fruit
type FRUIT
```

Now i need to search in `A.txt` for word `"FRUIT"` and copy the 2nd line on top of the `"FRUIT"` to a new file named `list.txt`.

But I only need the name of the fruit, where the `list.txt` should be looks like below.

```
APPLE
ORANG
CHERY
```

This is my coding (powershell) to do this...

```
$source = "C:\temp\A.txt"
$destination = "C:\temp\list.txt"
$hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "type FRUIT" -CaseSensitive
$filecontents = get-content $source
foreach($hit in $hits)
{
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-3]| out-file -append $destination
    "" |out-file -append $destination
}
```

This will extract the 2nd top line as per below

```
name APPLE
name ORANG
name CHERY
```

And below coding (.bat) will remove the word `"name"`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

del list2.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set chars=!line:~-13,13!
  echo !chars! >> list2.txt
)
```

As a 2nd phase now I need to search for word in `list.txt` file (`APPLE`,`ORANG`,`CHERY`) in my `B.txt`, which will look like below.

```
ITEM
p_date 10/03/15
pt_time 11:29:40:00
title nice coffe drink
name TICKY
stock yes
end
ITEM
p_date 10/03/15
pt_time 11:29:40:00
title sweet tasty apple
name APPLE
stock yes
end
ITEM
p_date 10/03/15
pt_time 11:29:40:00
title nice tasty drink
name JUICE
stock yes
end
ITEM
p_date 10/03/15
pt_time 11:29:40:00
title niice nice orange
name ORANG
stock yes
end
ITEM
p_date 10/03/15
pt_time 11:29:40:00
title nutritious rich fruit
name CHERY
stock yes
end
```

I must search for the words from `list.txt` in `B.txt` and extract the 3 top line and write it accordingly in a new file named `done.txt`. Below is my coding (powershell).

```
$source = "C:\temp\B.txt"
$destination = "C:\temp\done.txt"
$patterns = Get-Content c:\temp\list2.txt | Where-Object{$_}
$results = Select-String c:\temp\done.txt -Pattern $patterns -SimpleMatch
$results.Line | ForEach-Object{"$_`r`n"} | Set-Content c:\temp\done.txt
foreach($hit in $hits)
{
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-4]| out-file -append $destination
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-3]| out-file -append $destination
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-2]| out-file -append $destination
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-1]| out-file -append $destination
    "" |out-file -append $destination
}
```

I managed to develop coding for this. but I need 3 script file (2 powershell and 1 batch) to complete this operation.

Kindly assist me to complete this task in one single script. It will be best if it's in .vbs or .bat.

Comment: I think you need to take a few steps back, look at it again and re-factor.  Extracting the fruit names from the "name FRUIT" strings seems pointless if you're going back with it to match other "name FRUIT" strings. You had an exact match for what you're looking for to start with.  Also, you say you need 2 Powershell scripts, and then that "It will be best if it's in .vbs or .bat".  I don't think anybody is going to want to spend much of their Saturday trying to jump through that hoop,

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  I had to do a bit of creative work to make this all fit together.  For instance, instead of two scripts, I first search B.txt for fruit names that match what we have in A.txt, and I build an array of custom objects, to make it easier to search, as seen here:

```
    #Mark the word ITEM as the start of each record
$BHits = Select-String -Path $BSource -SimpleMatch "ITEM" -CaseSensitive -Context 5

#Make an empty array to hold our PowerShell Objects
$fruitMatches = @()
$output = @()

#Make $FruitMatches contain our purchase records
ForEach ($bhit in $BHits){
    $fruitMatches += [pscustomobject]@{Fruit=$BHit.Context.PostContext[3].Replace("name ",'');
        Date=$BHit.Context.PostContext[0].Replace('p_date ','');
        Time=$BHit.Context.PostContext[1].Replace('pt_time ','')}
}
```

Why do I bother doing that?  Well, first, you wanted to remove the word Name from your Select-String output.  As it turns out, you can do that pretty easily by using -Context to tell PowerShell to scrape a certain amount of lines along with a match, and selecting the particular line you want is as easy as indexing into the object like this:

```
#In one line, find the word type Fruit, and remove the word 'name'
($hit.Context.PreContext[0].Replace('name','').Trim()) 
>Cherry
```

Know for now that when you see that long string of `$hit.Context...` that it will resolve to just the name of the fruit.  Well, the reason we bothered making custom objects, is that I can then easily search through the matching objects like this:

```
ForEach ($hit in $hits){

    $fruitMatches | ? Fruit -eq ($hit.Context.PreContext[0].Replace('name','').Trim()) 
    }
```

Which will give us the following output:

```
Fruit                                  Date                                   Time                                 
-----                                  ----                                   ----                                 
APPLE                                  10/03/15                               11:29:40:00                          
ORANG                                  10/03/15                               11:29:40:00                          
CHERY                                  10/03/15                               11:29:40:00
```

From this point, I just create a few empty arrays to hold the results, and end the whole thing by dumping the output using the redirect character `>`.

This answers your whole premise with one script.  Please let me know if you have any questions about how this works.

**Completed Answer**

```
$source = "T:\A.txt"
$BSource = "t:\b.txt"
$destination = "T:\done.txt"


#Mark the word ITEM as the start of each record
$BHits = Select-String -Path $BSource -SimpleMatch "ITEM" -CaseSensitive -Context 5

#Make an empty array to hold our PowerShell Objects
$fruitMatches = @()
$output = @()

#Make $FruitMatches contain our purchase records
ForEach ($bhit in $BHits){
    $fruitMatches += [pscustomobject]@{Fruit=$BHit.Context.PostContext[3].Replace("name ",'');
        Date=$BHit.Context.PostContext[0].Replace('p_date ','');
        Time=$BHit.Context.PostContext[1].Replace('pt_time ','')}
}

#Resolve our Hits, looking in file A.txt for the line type FRUIT
$hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "type FRUIT" -CaseSensitive -Context 2
ForEach ($hit in $hits){

    $output += $fruitMatches | ? Fruit -eq ($hit.Context.PreContext[0].Replace('name','').Trim()) 
    }


$output > $destination
Write-Output "Checking $destination for matches"
Get-content $destination
```

Answer (score 0):

pure batch solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM create temporary numbered files:
findstr /n "^" a.txt >tempA.txt
findstr /n "^" b.txt >tempB.txt

(
  REM search for "type FRUIT" and fetch (linenumber-2)
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /c:"type FRUIT" tempA.txt') do (
    set /a line=%%a-2

    REM get content of this line:
    for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%d in ('findstr /b "!line!:" tempA.txt') do (

      REM get Fruit-linenumbers of B.txt:
      for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%g in ('findstr /c:"name %%e" tempB.txt') do (
        set /a line3=%%g-3
        set /a line2=%%g-2
        set /a line1=%%g-1      

        REM get the desired three lines from B.txt      
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%j in ('findstr /b "!line3!: !line2!: !line1!: " tempB.txt') do (
          echo %%k
        )
      )
    )
    echo.
  )
)>done.txt
del temp?.txt
type done.txt
```

The basic trick is, to add line numbers to the files, look for the searchstring and calculate the linenumbers of the desired line(s).

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below should run fast because it use just internal commands, but it is limited to a maximum of 1364 fruits in file A.txt. If you have more, the method may be modified to use an auxiliary file and process it with `findstr`, but in this case the program would run slower.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create list of fruit names from A.txt
set "list=/"
set "type="
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (A.txt) do (
   set "%%a=%%b"
   if "!type!" equ "FRUIT" (
      set "list=!list!!name!/"
      set "type="
   )
)

rem Extract 3 lines from B.txt
set "name="
(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (B.txt) do (
   set "%%a=%%b"
   for %%c in (!name!) do (
      if "!list:/%%c/=!" neq "%list%" (
         echo p_date !p_date!
         echo pt_time !pt_time!
         echo title !title!
         echo/
         set "name="
      )
   )
)) > done.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure batch solution with next key thoughts and/or limitations:

- solution with disabled delayed expansion;
- solution with no auxiliary files;
- output to a CSV-like file;
- treats faster `B.txt` file with supposedly unique appearance of a particular fruit (a stock list) if called without any parameter; in this case outputs the first occurrence of a particular fruit;
- capable to treat multiple appearance of a particular fruit in `B.txt` file (sales slip list) if called with a non-empty parameter, see output below;
- with no limit on different fruit number in the `A.txt` file. Ridiculous *advantage*, of course as hard to mind or even enumerate more than 1364 fruits :))
- probably slower than Stephan's and Aacini's solution, especially with growing input files.

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "multipleFruitInBfile=%~1"
echo "name";"title";"p_date";"pt_time"> 29319122done.txt
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in (29319122A.txt) do (
    set "A%%G=%%H"
    if /I "A%%G"=="Atype" if /I "%%H"=="FRUIT" (
        call :forFruit
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
type 29319122done.txt
goto :eof

:forFruit
SETLOCAL
for /F "tokens=1*" %%g in (29319122B.txt) do (
    set "%%g=%%h"
    if "%%g"=="name" if "%%h"=="%Aname%" (
        call :forEcho 
        if "%multipleFruitInBfile%"=="" goto :eof
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:forEcho
echo "%name%";"%title%";"%p_date%";"%pt_time%">> 29319122done.txt
goto :eof
```

Output (with doubled *ORANG* record in `B.txt` file):

```
==>D:\bat\29319122.bat
"name";"title";"p_date";"pt_time"
"APPLE";"sweet tasty apple";"10/03/15";"11:29:41:00"
"ORANG";"niice nice orange";"10/03/15";"11:29:43:00"
"CHERY";"nutritious rich fruit";"10/03/15";"11:29:44:00"

==>D:\bat\29319122.bat 1
"name";"title";"p_date";"pt_time"
"APPLE";"sweet tasty apple";"10/03/15";"11:29:41:00"
"ORANG";"niice nice orange";"10/03/15";"11:29:43:00"
"ORANG";"niice nice orange";"11/03/15";"11:29:45:00"
"CHERY";"nutritious rich fruit";"10/03/15";"11:29:44:00"

==>
```